# Set the initialpose (ROS2)

Tags: gazebo, ros2, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am still relatively new to ROS2 and am currently working on getting my digital Turtlebot3 to drive around in a Gazebo environment. I'm using ROS2 foxy on Ubuntu 20.04 and for navigation I use navigation2.

I then execute the following commands:

- `ros2 launch gazebo_ros gzserver.launch.py world:=/home/.../env.world`
- `ros2 run gazebo_ros spawn_entity.py -file /home/.../environment.sdf -entity environment`
- `ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo robot_state_publisher.launch.py`
- `ros2 launch nav2_bringup bringup_launch.py use_sim_time:=True autostart:=True map:=/home/map.yaml`

Now the following error occurs at the last command.

```
[amcl-2] [WARN] [1620937828.832260000] [amcl]: ACML cannot publish a pose or update the transform. Please set the initial pose...
```

How do I set the initial pose? I know that you can do it via Rviz, but in this case I want to solve it without RViz (with a command or programmatically via rclpy).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378514/set-the-initialpose-(ros2)/) by [RamiAW](https://answers.ros.org/users/74505/ramiaw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-05-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two options that I know of if you do not want to use RVIZ to set the initial pose:

1. the [amcl_node](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/2fcc2c2178ae3f269d87eb83de6acbb3a381d7cd/nav2_amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L121-L140) supports a `set_initial_pose` argument, as well as `initial_pose.x`, .y, .z, and .yaw. You can modify your launch files accordingly so this is set to your known or best guess initial position.
2. (probably the easier method) is to publish a message to the `/intialpose` topic. That should look something like this from the commandline:

   ros2 topic pub -1 /initialpose geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped '{ header: {stamp: {sec: 0, nanosec: 0}, frame_id: "map"}, pose: { pose: {position: {x: 0.1, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, orientation: {w: 0.1}}, } }'

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3